# Incompatibility in firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm about to finish my first web project and when I'm checking the browsers I find that firefox causes me the following error in the footer.

view Chrome:

[image]

view Firefox:

[image]

As you can see in other browsers it works and it looks perfectly in firefox, it is the only one that creates that space for me, if you can help me I would appreciate it. Here is the code:

```css
footer 
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 2050px;
    height: 330px;
}

footer div#aboutme
{
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

footer div#aboutme h3
{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

footer div#aboutme p
{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

footer div.rrss
{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0px;
    top: -300px;
    left: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

footer div.rrss p
{
    padding-top: 30px;
}

footer div.rrss a
{
    padding-top: 15px;
}

footer div.suscription
{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0px;
    top: -300px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

footer div.suscription p
{
    display: block;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

footer div.suscription input:nth-of-type(1)
{
    max-width: 175px;
}

footer div.suscription input:nth-of-type(2)
{
    max-width: 125px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

footer div#derechos
{
    position: relative;
    top: -299px;
}

footer div#derechos p
{
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <div id="aboutme">
        <h3>Acerca de mí...</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>


    <div class="rrss">
        <p><strong>Encuentrame en:</strong></p>
        <a href="#"></a>
        <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
        <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
        <a href="#"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="suscription">
        <p>Recibe nuestras publicaciones en tu email.</p>
        <input type="mail" name="email" placeholder="Ingresa tu email" id="input_registro">
        <input type="button" id="button_registro" name="button_registro" value="Registrar">
    </div>

    <div id="derechos">
        <p>© 2018 All rights reserved | Privacity Policy</p>
    </div>

</footer>
```

Comment: A fixed `top` for the footer seems bad to me why don't you say `bottom: 0` or `bottom: <footer height>` it would make it a lot more dynamic

Answer (score 1):

this is where comes from your trouble :

```
footer div.rrss
{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0px;
    top: -300px;
    left: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Firefox moves it up at screen but does not free that space.

add `overflow:hidden` to footer to keep it 300px of height

```css
footer 
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 2050px;
    height: 330px;
    overflow:hidden; /* will not keep space used by the relative element */
}

footer div#aboutme
{
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

footer div#aboutme h3
{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

footer div#aboutme p
{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

footer div.rrss
{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0px;
    top: -300px;
    left: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

footer div.rrss p
{
    padding-top: 30px;
}

footer div.rrss a
{
    padding-top: 15px;
}

footer div.suscription
{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0px;
    top: -300px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

footer div.suscription p
{
    display: block;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

footer div.suscription input:nth-of-type(1)
{
    max-width: 175px;
}

footer div.suscription input:nth-of-type(2)
{
    max-width: 125px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

footer div#derechos
{
    position: relative;
    top: -299px;
}

footer div#derechos p
{
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <div id="aboutme">
        <h3>Acerca de mí...</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>


    <div class="rrss">
        <p><strong>Encuentrame en:</strong></p>
        <a href="#"></a>
        <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
        <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
        <a href="#"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="suscription">
        <p>Recibe nuestras publicaciones en tu email.</p>
        <input type="mail" name="email" placeholder="Ingresa tu email" id="input_registro">
        <input type="button" id="button_registro" name="button_registro" value="Registrar">
    </div>

    <div id="derechos">
        <p>© 2018 All rights reserved | Privacity Policy</p>
    </div>

</footer>
```

You may also consider grid for the layout of the footer :

```css
footer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2050px;
  height: 350px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  background: #444;
  color: white;
}

footer div#aboutme {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

footer div#aboutme h3 {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

footer div#aboutme p {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

footer div.rrss {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

footer div.rrss p {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

footer div.rrss a {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

footer div.suscription {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

footer div.suscription p {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

footer div.suscription input:nth-of-type(1) {
  max-width: 175px;
}

footer div.suscription input:nth-of-type(2) {
  max-width: 125px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

footer div#derechos {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  margin: auto;
}

footer div#derechos p {}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div id="aboutme">
    <h3>Acerca de mí...</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>


  <div class="rrss">
    <p><strong>Encuentrame en:</strong></p>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
    <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="suscription">
    <p>Recibe nuestras publicaciones en tu email.</p>
    <input type="mail" name="email" placeholder="Ingresa tu email" id="input_registro">
    <input type="button" id="button_registro" name="button_registro" value="Registrar">
  </div>

  <div id="derechos">
    <p>© 2018 All rights reserved | Privacity Policy</p>
  </div>

</footer>
```